# How can I find the dimension of this vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

This question was asked in my assignment of linear algebra and I am not able to make any significant progress on this question.

> Question: Let $V$ be the space of all linear transformations from $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ under usual addition and scalar  multiplication. Then show that $V$ is a vector space of dimension $6$.

Attempt: I think $V$ is a vector space of dimension $4$ with basis as matrix $A,B,C,D$ and all of them are $2 \times 2$ matrix with $A$ has $a_{11}=1 $ and rest all terms zero and $B$ has $a_{12} =1$ and rest all zero and so on.

But I don't know how answer is $6$.

Can you please help?

Comment: I think 'linear transformations' here actually means 'affine transformations'. Namelly,  such map doesn't necessarily keeps (0, 0) fixed.

Comment: The true answer to the question is 4. So either the given answer is wrong, or the question was supposed to be different.

Answer (score 0):

The general inhomogenous  linear transformation between two spaces with basis $(v_i),(w_j)$ is  fixed by the image of the basis $$L(v_i)  =   p_i + \sum_j q_{i,k} w_j,$$ that is a translation by a 2d vector plus multiplication by a 2x2 matrix.

The addition of two linear forms is defined by separate parallel addition on the translation $R^2$ and the addition of  the matrices  in $\mathbb R^{2\times2}$ $$ a\ L_1(p_1,m_1)\oplus b \ L_2(p_2,m_2) =L(a\  p_1+b \ p_2,a \  m_1+b \ m_2)$$